# Django Error Module 'Whitenoise' not found

Tags: python, django, whitenoise

I'm using whitenoise to deploy static files in prod, so according to whitenoise's docs, it's recommended to use it in development too.

So I followed the documentation and added the following to my `settings.py` file:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'whitenoise.runserver_nostatic',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    ...other
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    ...other
]
```

But when I run the server using `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`, I get the error

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'whitenoise'

Full stack trace:

```
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/path/to/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/path/to/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/path/to/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 76, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "/path/to/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 357, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "/path/to/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/path/to/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/path/to/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/path/to/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 116, in create
    mod = import_module(mod_path)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'whitenoise'
```

I checked using `pip freeze` and the module IS installed (v5.0.1) along with django 3.0.4.  So why am I getting that error?

Comment: did you find any solution to this?

Comment: @FedericoCapaldo no but I got my staic files working a different way.  In my urls.py I put `from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns` and `urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()`  This generates a URL for every static file.  Not sure about performance comparisons though, but it works with Uvicorn, which was what I was trying to use.

Comment: I solved the problem by installing whitenose globally (`pip install whitenoise`) in addition to having installed the package in my current virualenv (`bin/activate && pipenv install whitenoise`).

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are installing whitenoise globally or within your working virtual environment. In my case, I had installed it globally and was expecting it to work within my project that was running in a virtual environment. I had to install it as well in the virtual environment to get it to work (resolve the issue)

Answer (score -1):

this issue will be resolved  by installing whitenose module  to your virtual environment or globally.

```
pip install whitenoise
```